# What packages should be installed to use ALSA library?

Tags: c++, alsa, portaudio

I am trying to create an C++ application for recording which uses the PortAudio interface ( I want to use ALSA instead of JACK ). I have read and followed the tutorial in the website
[PortAudio](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html).
I have installed libasound, but when I compiled

```
g++ -lrt -lasound -lalsa -lpthread main.cpp libportaudio.a
```

it occured this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lalsa
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think I don't have ALSA library so I use synaptic package to install it. But there are too many packages about ALSA. Can you suggest me what packages I should install?

Comment: `apt-get install libasound2-dev`?

Answer (score 0):

ALSA should be part of a standard install.  If I remember correctly the only library required is libasound (I've always assumed that stood for alsa sound).

If you haven't seen it yet, this howto explains how to build on Linux.  The example uses JACK.  I believe JACK relies on ALSA as well.

[Using PortAudio in your Projects](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it still remained the same error:"cannot find -lalsa" :(

Comment: Use -lasound not -lalsa